# How can Python class have a new attribute without declaring it in the class definition?

Tags: python, class, attributes

```py
>> class Car:
>>    pass

>> car = Car()
>> car.var = 1
```

This stoped me for a second when I saw this is possible.
How can `car.var = 1` be possible without attribute `var` never being declared in the class definition of `Car`? I've been using C, C++, Java in the last two years, I can't see what I'm missing to understand this.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: might this help your understanding? https://dzone.com/articles/python-class-attributes-vs-instance-attributes

Comment: Because ... it's allowed in Python. Python is different from C++ and Java.

Comment: I can see it being confusing from a C, C++ and Java perspective. However, here `car.var = 1` is the declaration of the attribute `var`.

Comment: Note that in your example you are setting value of attribute of _instance_, not attribute of _class_.